# How to add an xml node to a specific place in an xml document in C#

Tags: c#, xml, nodes

**XML File Data**

```
<xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Module xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Table="" Type="Process Start" ReadOnly="false" xmlns="http://localhost/License2000/xml/ModuleSchema.xsd">
 <Attributes>...</Attributes>
 <Clients>
   <Client Name="*">
     <Processes>
       <Process Name="ren">...</Process>
       <Process Name="dup">...</Process>
       <Process Name="DEM">...</Process>
       <Process Name="LAC">...</Process>
       <Process Name="APP">
         <Agencies>
           <Agency Name="1">
             <Professions>
               <Profession Name="4">
                  <LicenseTypes>
                    <LicenseType Name="202">
                      <Controls Role="*">
                        <Control Visible="true" Type="com.sac.eLicense.Controls.Label" ReadOnly="false" Required="false" Value="&lt;p class=MsoNormal&gt;&lt;b&gt;&lt;span style='font-size:11.0pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,&quot;sans-serif&quot;'&gt;Please&#xD;&#xA;read the following information and requirements for initial licensure as an&#xD;&#xA;associate broker standard carefully before proceeding with the online process.&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;&lt;p class=MsoNormal&gt;&lt;b&gt;&lt;u&gt;&lt;span style='font-size:11.0pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,&quot;sans-serif&quot;'&gt;If&#xD;&#xA;you have ever held a Broker license in Pennsylvania please STOP. &lt;/span&gt;&lt;/u&gt;&lt;/b&gt;&lt;b&gt;&lt;u&gt;&lt;span&#xD;&#xA;style='font-size:11.0pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,&quot;sans-serif&quot;'&gt;DO NOT CONTINUE.&#xD;&#xA;Contact the Commission for instructions.&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/u&gt;&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;&lt;p class=MsoNormal&gt;&lt;span style='font-size:11.0pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,&quot;sans-serif&quot;'&gt;Please&#xD;&#xA;complete all items in the checklist on the left-side of the screen.&lt;span&#xD;&#xA;style='color:red'&gt;&amp;nbsp; &lt;/span&gt;Each item in the checklist must be completed&#xD;&#xA;before you can pay the required fee and submit the application.&amp;nbsp; Upon&#xD;&#xA;completing each checklist item a checkmark will appear in the box next to the&#xD;&#xA;item&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;&lt;p class=MsoNormal&gt;&lt;b&gt;&lt;u&gt;&lt;span style='font-size:11.0pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,&quot;sans-serif&quot;'&gt;Examination:&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/u&gt;&lt;/b&gt;&lt;span&#xD;&#xA;style='font-size:11.0pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,&quot;sans-serif&quot;'&gt;&amp;nbsp; A passing&#xD;&#xA;score on the Pennsylvania (state) portion and the national (general) portion of&#xD;&#xA;the broker examination within the past three years OR in lieu of the national&#xD;&#xA;(general) portion of the examination have been licensed&amp;nbsp;and active as a&#xD;&#xA;real estate broker in another jurisdiction within the past five&#xD;&#xA;years. &lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;&lt;p class=MsoNormal&gt;&lt;b&gt;&lt;span style='font-size:11.0pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,&quot;sans-serif&quot;'&gt;*Licensees&#xD;&#xA;who wish to use and advertise a nickname for their first name shall include the&#xD;&#xA;nickname on their licensure applications or biennial renewal applications. &lt;/span&gt;&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&#xD;&#xA;&lt;br/&gt;&lt;br/&gt;" PageRow="0" PageColumn="0" Rowspan="1" Colspan="1" CID="AppInstructionsLabel" System="false" NodeLevel="License Type">
                          <Attributes>
                            <Attribute Name="class" Value="label" />
                          </Attributes>
                        </Control>
                        <Control Visible="true" Type="com.sac.eLicense.Controls.HyperLink" ReadOnly="false" Required="false" Value="Next..." PageRow="2" PageColumn="0" Rowspan="1" Colspan="1" CID="hyperlink_next" System="false" NodeLevel="License Type">
                          <Attributes>
                            <Attribute Name="href" Value="Demographics.aspx" />
                          </Attributes>
                        </Control>
                      </Controls>
                    </LicenseType>
                     .
                     .
                     .
                  </LicenseTypes>
                </Profession>
              </Professions>
            </Agency>
          </Agencies>
        </Process>
      </Processes>
    </Client>
  </Clients>
</Module>
```

I need to add the following node only beneath the Process where Name = "APP" for every license type that appears beneath it. It must be a child of the Controls node; i.e. a sibling to the other Control nodes.

```
                        <Control Visible="true" Type="com.sac.eLicense.Controls.Label" ReadOnly="false" Required="false" Value="&lt;body&gt;&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;&lt;p&gt;&lt;font face=&quot;Arial&quot; size=&quot;3&quot;&gt;&lt;b&gt;TEST LABEL&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&#xD;&#xA;&lt;p class=&quot;MsoNormal&quot; align=&quot;center&quot; style=&quot;text-align:center&quot;&gt;&lt;b&gt;&lt;font face=&quot;Arial&quot; size=&quot;2&quot;&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;mso-bidi-font-size: 12.0pt&quot;&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;o:p&gt;&#xD;&#xA;&lt;/o:p&gt;&#xD;&#xA;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&#xD;&#xA;&lt;font face=&quot;Arial&quot; size=&quot;2&quot;&gt;&#xD;&#xA;&lt;span style=&quot;mso-bidi-font-size: 12.0pt; mso-fareast-font-family: Times New Roman; mso-ansi-language: EN-US; mso-fareast-language: EN-US; mso-bidi-language: AR-SA&quot;&gt;&lt;br clear=&quot;all&quot; style=&quot;mso-special-character:line-break;&#xD;&#xA;page-break-before:always&quot;&gt;&#xD;&#xA;&lt;/span&gt;&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;&lt;/font&gt;&#xD;&#xA;&lt;/body&gt;" PageRow="0" PageColumn="0" Rowspan="1" Colspan="1" CID="AppInstructionsLabel" System="false" NodeLevel="License Type">
                          <Attributes>
                            <Attribute Name="class" Value="label" />
                          </Attributes>
                        </Control>
```

I have used the following code to be able to navigate to the process name = "APP", but from there I am unable to then select the Controls nodes and add children nodes per the example above. Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.XPath;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(@"C:\Users\c-jerbaker\Desktop\ProcessStart.xml");
            XmlNodeList processNodes = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Process");
            foreach (XmlNode processNode in processNodes)
            {
                XmlAttributeCollection attributeCollection = processNode.Attributes;
                foreach (XmlAttribute attribute in attributeCollection)
                {
                    if (attribute.Value == "APP")
                    {
                        XmlNodeList controlNodes = processNode.SelectNodes("Controls");
                        foreach (XmlNode controlNode in controlNodes)
                        //{

                        //    XmlNode node = doc.CreateElement("Control");
                        //    XmlAttribute attribute2 = doc.CreateAttribute("Visible");
                        //    attribute2.Value = "true";
                        //    node.Attributes.Append(attribute2);
                        //    attribute2 = doc.CreateAttribute("Type");
                        //    attribute2.Value = "com.sac.eLicense.Controls.Label";
                        //    node.Attributes.Append(attribute2);
                        //    attribute2 = doc.CreateAttribute("ReadOnly");
                        //    attribute2.Value = "false";
                        //    node.Attributes.Append(attribute2);
                        //    attribute2 = doc.CreateAttribute("Required");
                        //    attribute2.Value = "false";
                        //    node.Attributes.Append(attribute2);
                        //    attribute2 = doc.CreateAttribute("Value");
                        //    attribute2.Value = "&lt;body&gt;&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;&lt;p&gt;&lt;font face=&quot;Arial&quot; size=&quot;3&quot;&gt;&lt;b&gt;TEST LABEL&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&#xD;&#xA;&lt;p class=&quot;MsoNormal&quot; align=&quot;center&quot; style=&quot;text-align:center&quot;&gt;&lt;b&gt;&lt;font face=&quot;Arial&quot; size=&quot;2&quot;&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;mso-bidi-font-size: 12.0pt&quot;&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;o:p&gt;&#xD;&#xA;&lt;/o:p&gt;&#xD;&#xA;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&#xD;&#xA;&lt;font face=&quot;Arial&quot; size=&quot;2&quot;&gt;&#xD;&#xA;&lt;span style=&quot;mso-bidi-font-size: 12.0pt; mso-fareast-font-family: Times New Roman; mso-ansi-language: EN-US; mso-fareast-language: EN-US; mso-bidi-language: AR-SA&quot;&gt;&lt;br clear=&quot;all&quot; style=&quot;mso-special-character:line-break;&#xD;&#xA;page-break-before:always&quot;&gt;&#xD;&#xA;&lt;/span&gt;&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;&lt;/font&gt;&#xD;&#xA;&lt;/body&gt;";
                        //    node.Attributes.Append(attribute2);
                        //    attribute2 = doc.CreateAttribute("PageRow");
                        //    attribute2.Value = "0";
                        //    node.Attributes.Append(attribute2);
                        //    attribute2 = doc.CreateAttribute("PageColumn");
                        //    attribute2.Value = "0";
                        //    node.Attributes.Append(attribute2);
                        //    attribute2 = doc.CreateAttribute("Rowspan");
                        //    attribute2.Value = "2";
                        //    node.Attributes.Append(attribute2);
                        //    attribute2 = doc.CreateAttribute("Colspan");
                        //    attribute2.Value = "1";
                        //    node.Attributes.Append(attribute2);
                        //    attribute2 = doc.CreateAttribute("CID");
                        //    attribute2.Value = "AppInstructionsLabel";
                        //    node.Attributes.Append(attribute2);
                        //    attribute2 = doc.CreateAttribute("System");
                        //    attribute2.Value = "false";
                        //    node.Attributes.Append(attribute2);
                        //    attribute2 = doc.CreateAttribute("NodeLevel");
                        //    attribute2.Value = "LicenseType";
                        //    node.Attributes.Append(attribute2);

                        //    controlNode.AppendChild(node);


                        //    doc.Save("ProcessStart.xml");
                        //    Console.ReadLine();

                        //}

                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The commented section is where I try to build the node to add, but without being able to get to those consoles nodes I can't even begin to test if I'm doing the next part right. I've been searching all over the net trying to figure out more about XML navigation and creation, but at this point I'm stumped. IF someone can point me in the right direction or explain to me what I'm not understanding about XML I'd appreciate it.

Thanks.